# Repeating a string `x` number of times without an if block

Tags: php

Is there any way to repeat a string an arbitrary number of times?  I have this code, and I feel like there should be a simpler way of doing it.

```
    $vitals = parent::userVitals($uid);
    $hearts = round($vitals['health']/25);
    /* with our powers combined! */
    if($hearts == 4)
    {
        $health = "&hearts;&hearts;&hearts;&hearts;";
    }
    elseif($hearts == 3)
    {
        $health = "&hearts;&hearts;&hearts;";

    }
    elseif($hearts == 2)
    {
        $health = "&hearts;&hearts;";
    }
    elseif($hearts == 1)
    {
        $health = "&hearts;";
    }
    return $health;
```

Comment: How is this question related to PDO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `for-loop` like

```
$vitals = parent::userVitals($uid);
$hearts = round($vitals['health']/25);

$health = "";
for( $i=0 ; $i < $hearts ; $i++) {
   $health .= "&hearts;";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$health = str_repeat('&hearts;', $hearts);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

PHP is filled with random functions like this.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I wasn't looking to reinvent the wheel. I actually googled the heek out of this before posting it here, i guess i was just using the wrong terminology for the search.

Comment: @user1030841, No worries, it wasn't a criticism.  Just pointing out that there are weird functions like this in PHP that don't typically exist in other standard libraries.

Comment: Which is good to know! Though, as much as i like PHP... i still hate their website... It hasn't been updated in forever... i mean, they've just unleashed a new theme but the manual is still cluttered and confusing to me.

Comment: @user1030841, The website is updated very regularly... doesn't seem so cluttered and confusing to me.  It's documentation, not a tutorial.  You might be better off looking at some tutorials elsewhere to get started.